# Add 2 Classes in ERB - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'd like to add more than one class to the submit button in a form.

I know you can add a class by doing `:class => "btn"` but how do I add 2?

Comment: Putting two classes in the string?

Comment: Tried. I'm getting an error.

Comment: Aaaaand the error is...? Please try to make your questions complete from the outset instead of making people dig.

Comment: How is this question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

separate your classes with spaces

```
:class => "btn some other classes go crazy"
```

Comment: does that answer your question?